# Linear map, inner products and orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

If $L: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ is any map and we have two inner products defined on $\mathbb{V}$, $[ , ]$ and $⟨ , ⟩$, and we pick two orthonormal bases w.r.t. each of these inner products, how can one prove that if $L(B) = A$ (where $A$ and $B$ are the two bases), then $L$ preserves the inner product, and thus $[x, y] = ⟨L(x), L(y)⟩$?

I know it must be easy, but I got confused and lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, I am assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional, of dimension $n$. Let $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis w.r.t $[\cdot,\cdot]$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis w.r.t. $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Then we are given that there exists a permutation $\pi$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $L(v_i) = w_{\pi(i)}$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$. (This is just expressing the fact that $L$ maps one basis to the other.)

By relabelling the $w_j$'s if necessary, we can assume $L(v_i) = w_i$.

If, $x,y \in V$, we can write $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_iv_i$ and $y = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_jv_j$, so as $[v_i,v_j] = 0$ unless $i = j$,

\begin{equation}
[x,y] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_ib_i.
\end{equation}

But also, $L(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_iw_{i}$, and $L(y) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_jw_{j}$.

As $\langle w_{i}, w_{j}\rangle = 0$ unless $i = j$, we see that 
\begin{equation}
\langle L(x), L(y)\rangle = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_ib_i = [x,y].
\end{equation}

Comment: Because $[x, y]$ is not necessarily a dot product, how can we be sure that $[x, y] = \Sigma_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$? Can it be equal to, say, $\Sigma_{i=1}^n 2a_i b_i$?

Comment: We know $[x,y] = [\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_iv_i, \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_jv_j]$. Now apply bi-linearity of the inner-product, and the fact that $[v_i,v_j] = 0$ unless $i = j$, and $[v_i,v_i] = 1$. This gives $[x,y] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_ib_j[v_i,v_j] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_ib_i$. Note: I have assumed in my answer this is a vector space over the **reals** (if over the complex numbers, then $[x,y] = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i\overline{b_i}$.)

Comment: What if the inner product is defined in a way like this: $[\vec{x}, \vec{y}] = 2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_1 x_2$, will it still hold that $\Sigma_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{j=1}^n a_i b_j [v_i, v_j] = [\Sigma_{i=1}^n a_i v_i, \Sigma_{j=1}^n b_j v_j]$?

Comment: I'm not sure your definition makes sense the way you have written it there: How does $x_1$ and $x_2$ relate to $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$? Does $\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: It was just a special case example.